# Can't seem to get a code block to be formatted correctly

Tags: support, code-formatting, markdown

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20008859), I have a code block:

```cs
public class LocalizedStrings 
{ 
    public string this[string key] 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return App.ResourceLoader.GetForViewIndependentUse().GetString(key); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

In this post, it gets formatted correctly, but I can't seem to get it to format properly in the linked answer. Is it because of the bullets used before it?

Comment: Adding in a HTML comment `<!-- -->` directly before the code will fix it.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/code-block-is-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-item

Comment: @JoshCrozier, it doesn't *have to* be blank.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're putting it directly after a list. A list uses the same indentation scheme as a code block to *continue a list item*. So, you have two options:

1. Indent your code *another* four spaces (eight spaces total), if you wish the code block to be a part of the final list item.
2. Add an empty comment (`<!-- -->`) after your list and before the code block to forcibly break out of the list and let the Markdown parser start a code block with normal indentation.